# Need help creating a Topological Sort diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote

does anyone have any ideas on how i can create a diagram like the following "Topological Sort" in LaTeX ? it can also be horizontal, does not need to be vertical.

Thanks in advance. [image: Topological Sort]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It can be done either with `TikZ` or `pstricks`.

Comment: Thank you :) anyone care to help me get started? Any help much appreciated!!

Comment: [welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) could you show us your [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible to do this using `tikz` or `pstricks` to do *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me", which show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of how to start.

Comment: i added my progress so far. thanks for the information

Answer (score 6):

A short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}%% auto-pst-pdf to compile with pdflatex
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
\foreach\value[count=\y] in {4,5,1,12,11,10,9,6,0,3,2,7,8}{\Cnodeput[radius=2.8mm](0,\y){\value}{\value}}
\rput(0,14){\Rnode{D}{\textcolor{IndianRed}{\itshape point down}}}
\psset{linewidth=0.6pt, linecolor=SteelBlue, arrows =-> ,arrowinset=0.12}
\foreach\be/\en in {8/7,2/3,0/6,6/9,9/10,11/12,5/4}{\ncline{\be}{\en}}
\ncline{D}{8}
\foreach\be/\en in {7/6,2/0,6/4,9/12}{\nccurve[angleA=-135, angleB=135]{\be}{\en}}
\nccurve[angleA=-125, angleB=125]{9}{11}
\nccurve[angleA=-40, angleB=40]{3}{5}
\nccurve[angleA=-35, angleB=60]{0}{5}
\nccurve[angleA=-50, angleB=60]{0}{1}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Some explanations about the code:*

I first scan the list of values to be displayed and put each item  (`\value`) in a `circle node` on the *y*-axis, with ordinate its order number in the list (`count=\y`) and with name the inserted value and place at the top the small red text as a rectangular nodenamed `D`.

Then I set  some parameters (line width, line colour, &c.).  Finally, nodes are connected either by  a straight line (`\ncline`) or by a Bézier curve (`\nccurve`). For these curves, I had to specify the angle w.r.t. the horizontal line at the beginning (`angleA` parameter) and at the end (`\angleB`) so the curves don't mess up.

Comment: I like your answer, but if you described your answer, it might be more helpful.

Comment: @alhelal: I've added some lines about the way it  was coded. Hope this is clear, but feel free to ask questions if it's not.

Comment: You can give a document reference that describe the implementation, so that anyone can get more information.

Comment: `Texdoc pst-node` is well documented, with many example, and od reasonable size. This supposes you know the basic  commands of `pstricks`. B.t.w., to compile with `pdflatex`, you have to set the compiler switch `--enable-write18` if you're under MiKTeX, or `-shell-escape for TeX Live or MacTeX. Alternatively, you can follow the old-style way  `latex+dvips+pstopdf`, or compile with `xelatex`.

Answer (score 6):

Using `Asymptote` object-oriented approach,
a class definition (file `gsort.asy`):

```
struct gSortSkin{
    real dx,dNode,dlink;
    guide contour;
    pen nodePen,nodeBgPen,labelPen,linkPen;
    arrowbar arr;
    string TeXlabelMacro="";

    void operator init(real dx, real dNode, real dlink, 
    guide contour,
    pen nodePen=currentpen,
    pen nodeBgPen=nullpen,
    pen labelPen=currentpen,
    pen linkPen=currentpen,
    arrowbar arr=Arrow,
    string TeXlabelMacro=""
    ){
        this.dx=dx; this.dNode=dNode; this.dlink=dlink; 
        this.contour=contour; 
        this.nodePen  =nodePen  ;
        this.nodeBgPen=nodeBgPen;
        this.labelPen =labelPen ;
        this.linkPen  =linkPen  ;
        this.arr=arr;  
        this.TeXlabelMacro=TeXlabelMacro; 
    }
}

gSortSkin colorSkin1=gSortSkin(
dx=0,dNode=18mm,dlink=16mm,
contour=circle((0,0),6mm),
nodePen=deepblue+0.5bp,
nodeBgPen=lightyellow,
labelPen=brown,
linkPen=orange+0.5bp,
arr=Arrow(HookHead,size=0.5,angle=60),
TeXlabelMacro=""
);

gSortSkin BWSkin=gSortSkin(
dx=0,dNode=18mm,dlink=16mm,
contour=circle((0,0),6mm),
nodePen=black+0.5bp,
nodeBgPen=white,
labelPen=black,
linkPen=black+0.5bp,
arr=Arrow(HookHead,size=0.5,angle=60),
TeXlabelMacro=""
);



struct gSort{
    picture pic;
    int n;
    int[] list;
    int[][][] aLinks;
    bool vertical;
    gSortSkin skin;
    pair[] elPos;
    transform tr;

    void drawLinks(){
        guide glink;

        for(int i=0;i<aLinks.length;++i){
            for(int j=0;j<aLinks[i].length;++j){        
                if(aLinks[i][j][1]>0){
                    glink=elPos[i]..((elPos[i]+elPos[i+aLinks[i][j][1]])/2+skin.dlink*aLinks[i][j][0])..elPos[i+aLinks[i][j][1]];
                    glink=cut(glink,shift(elPos[i])*skin.contour,1).after;
                    glink=cut(glink,shift(elPos[i+aLinks[i][j][1]])*skin.contour,1).before;
                    draw(pic,tr*glink,skin.linkPen,skin.arr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void draw(){
        pair v;
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
            v=(0,-i*skin.dNode);
            elPos[i]=v;
            filldraw(pic, tr*shift(v)*skin.contour,skin.nodeBgPen,skin.nodePen);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
            v=(0,-i*skin.dNode);
            label(pic,"$"+skin.TeXlabelMacro+"{"+string(list[i])+"}$",tr*v,skin.labelPen);
        }
        drawLinks();
    }

    void operator init(picture pic=currentpicture, 
    int[] list, 
    int[][][] aLinks,
    bool vertical=true,
    gSortSkin skin=colorSkin1
    ){
        this.pic=pic;
        this.list=list;
        this.n=list.length;
        this.aLinks=aLinks;
        this.elPos=new pair[];
        this.skin=skin;
        this.vertical=vertical;
        if(vertical){
            tr=identity();
        }else tr=rotate(90); 
    }
}
```

And an example of usage :

```
// gsorttest.asy
//
// run 
// asy gsorttest.asy
// to get gsorttest.pdf
//
settings.tex="pdflatex";
import gsort;
size(10cm); import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");

int[] nodeList={8,7,2,3,0,6,9,10,11,12,1,5,4};
int[][][] aLinks={ // for every node: {{left=-1,-2,;mid=0;right=1,2,}, 
                   //             {relative link to node from current node| 0, if no link}}
    {{ 0,+1}},
    {{-2,+4}},
    {{-1,+2},{0,+1}},
    {{+3,+8}},
    {{ 0,+1},{+1,+6},{+2,+7}},
    {{-3,+7},{0,+1}},
    {{-1,+2},{-2,+3},{ 0,+1}},
    {{ 0,0}},
    {{ 0,+1}},
    {{ 0,0}},
    {{ 0,0}},
    {{ 0,+1}},
    {{ 0,0}},
};

gSortSkin skin=colorSkin1;
skin.TeXlabelMacro="\mathtt";
skin.nodeBgPen=palegreen;
skin.nodePen=skin.nodePen+1.5bp;
skin.linkPen=lightblue;

gSort gs=gSort(nodeList,aLinks,vertical=false,skin=skin);

gs.draw();
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

i think i have done it correctly. please give me comments or suggestions :)

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,trees,positioning}
\tikzstyle{circleobject}=[circle,fill=white,draw,line width=0.5mm]
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw]
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[draw, -latex]

\begin{comment}
\end{comment}

\tikzset{%
    /forest,
    forest node/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, text centered},
    arn n/.append style={text=white, font=\sffamily\bfseries, draw=black, text width=1.5em},
    arn r/.append style={text=red, draw=red, text width=1.5em, very thick},
  }
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) node[circleobject] (Small2A) {3};
  \draw (1.5,0) node[circleobject] (Small2B) {7};
  \draw (3,0) node[circleobject] (Small2C) {1};
  \draw (4.5,0) node[circleobject] (Small2D) {0};
  \draw (6,0) node[circleobject] (Small2E) {5};
  \draw (7.5,0) node[circleobject] (Small2F) {2};
  \draw (9,0) node[circleobject] (Small2G) {6};
  \draw (10.5,0) node[circleobject] (Small2H) {4};
  \draw (12,0) node[circleobject] (Small2I) {8};
  \draw (13.5,0) node[circleobject] (Small2J) {9};
  %%
  \draw[-latex,bend left]  (Small2A) edge (Small2B);
  \draw[-latex,bend right]  (Small2A) edge (Small2I);
  \draw[-latex,bend left]  (Small2B) edge (Small2I);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: topological sort]

Comment: and some variables there are not needed..

Comment: i was just answering it as i figured out a solution. is it supposed to be done in some other way ?

Comment: if you wrote the answer for exact the question you asked, it was better. You can use `loop` to minimize writing text. see @Bernard's answer.