# How to add connected graphs to a table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

We have already seen how to create connected graphs with nodes:
[Easiest way to create simple connected graphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394942/easiest-way-to-create-simple-connected-graphs)

Where Ross, Bernard and Michael Palmer offered very good answers.

[image]
My question is now how to do the same with a table, without nodes but linking its elements.

Say we have this table:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \hline 
        ID & COLOR \\ 
        \hline 
        1 & blue \\ 
        1 & red \\ 
        1 & green \\ 
        1 & white \\ 
        \hline 
        2 & red \\ 
        2 & green \\        
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

What would be the easiest way to get something like this

[image]

PD:
OK, that seems to be too easy for you. Let's complicate it a little bit, to break ties, with two tables:

[image]

PD2:  One question, is it advisable to embed
all these code in the same document or "include" it or is it better to create the picture and save it as another pdf file?

Comment: Perso,ally, I would  make a standalone image and include the resulting .pdf  via `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @Bernard I find the externalize feature of `tikz`/`pgf` to be quite useful if I want to implement the image as code, as it will do the external generation and inclusion for you.

Comment: I would compile in a standalone (with the same font font size and so on, as in the main preamble.) Then include as pdf. This would speed up compilation in big projects. I would not resize in my compilation (such that font size is consistent). If I only compiled really rarely, or had a super computer just for compiling LaTeX I would include it in the main document.

Comment: I've created a new question about how to get all this with a GUI  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401264/how-to-insert-a-table-in-tikzedt-create-tikz-diagrams-with-tables-using-a-gui

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tikzmark` is the most common method.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \hline 
        ID & COLOR \\ 
        \hline 
        1 & \tikzmark{b1}  blue  \tikzmark{b2} \\ 
        1 & \tikzmark{r1}  red  \tikzmark{r2} \\ 
        1 & \tikzmark{g1}  green  \tikzmark{g2} \\ 
        1 & \tikzmark{w1}  white  \tikzmark{w2} \\ 
        \hline 
        2 & red \\ 
        2 & green \\        
    \end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,bend angle=45]
\draw [->] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:b1) to[bend right] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:w1);
\draw [->] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:b2) to[bend left] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:g2);
\draw [->,preaction={very thick,-,draw=white}] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:r2) to[bend left=60,looseness=1.2] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:w2);    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There's really not much more to it even for your complication, place a `\tikzmark{foo}` where you want an arrow to start or finish, and use `(pic cs:foo)` as a coordinate in a `tikzpicture` with `remember picture,overlay`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \hline 
        ID & COLOR \\ 
        \hline 
        1 & \tikzmark{b1}  blue  \tikzmark{b2} \\ 
        1 & \tikzmark{r1}  red  \tikzmark{r2} \\ 
        1 & \tikzmark{g1}  green  \tikzmark{g2} \\ 
        1 & \tikzmark{w1}  white  \tikzmark{w2} \\ 
        \hline 
        2 & red \\ 
        2 & green \\        
    \end{tabular}\tikzmark{T1}
    \caption{Foo}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
    \centering
        \tikzmark{T2}\begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \hline 
        ID & COLOR \\ 
        \hline 
        1 & \tikzmark{b2-1}  blue  \tikzmark{b2-2} \\ 
        1 & \tikzmark{r2-1}  red  \tikzmark{r2-2} \\ 
        1 & \tikzmark{g2-1}  green  \tikzmark{g2-2} \\ 
        1 & \tikzmark{w2-1}  white  \tikzmark{w2-2}
        \end{tabular}
       \caption{Bar}

        \vspace{2cm}        

        \tikzmark{T3}\begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \hline 
        2 & red \\ 
        2 & green \\        
       \end{tabular}
    \caption{Baz}
    \end{minipage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   remember picture,overlay,
   bend angle=45,
   smallarrows/.style={-stealth},
   bigarrows/.style={
      shorten >=3mm,shorten <=3mm,
      line width=1mm,
      -stealth
   }
]
\draw [smallarrows] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:b1) to[bend right] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:w1);
\draw [smallarrows] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:b2) to[bend left] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:g2);
\draw [smallarrows,preaction={very thick,-,draw=white}] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:r2) to[bend left=60,looseness=1.2] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:w2);

\draw [smallarrows] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:b2-1) to[bend right] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:w2-1);
\draw [smallarrows] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:b2-2) to[bend left] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:g2-2);
\draw [smallarrows,preaction={very thick,-,draw=white}] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:r2-2) to[bend left=60,looseness=1.2] ([yshift=1ex]pic cs:w2-2);    

\draw [bigarrows] (pic cs:T1) -- node[sloped,above] {Transformation} (pic cs:T2);
\draw [bigarrows] (pic cs:T1) -- (pic cs:T3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In hindsight though, it might be easier to add the text to the table as TikZ nodes. I.e. instead of writing `blue`, write `\tikz[baseline=(b.base),remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt,name=b]{blue};`.

`\tikz` is a shortform for `\begin{tikzpicture} .. \end{tikzpicture}`, the `baseline` key is properly align the text vertically on the baseline of the table row. `inner sep` is set to zero to not add any additional whitespace. `\node[name=a] {};` is the same as `\node (a) {};`.

Much better to make a macro of that of course, so for example:

[image: output of below code]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tablenode}[2]{\tikz[baseline=(#1.base),remember picture]\node[inner sep=0pt,name=#1]{#2};}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \hline 
        ID & COLOR \\ 
        \hline 
        1 & \tablenode{b}{blue} \\[10pt]
        1 & \tablenode{r}{red} \\ 
        1 & \tablenode{g}{green} \\ 
        1 & \tablenode{w}{white} \\ 
        \hline 
        2 & red \\ 
        2 & green \\        
    \end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  remember picture,overlay,
  >=stealth
]
\draw [->] (b) -- (r);
\draw [->] (b) to[out=180,in=180,looseness=0.6] (g);
\draw [->] (b.south east) to[out=300,in=60] (w.north east);
\draw [->,preaction={very thick,-,draw=white}] (r) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=2] (w.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've added a complication to break ties.

Comment: When I apply it 
 to my real data I have this small problem https://i.imgur.com/NlYF1a0.png  the arrows overlap too much.  What's the parameter to shorten them a little bit or the parameter to move the tikzmark slightly?  I've tried with shorten, https://i.imgur.com/RGP8o7Y.png  but I don't know if it's the proper way.

Comment: The problem is worse when 3 o 4 arrows arrive to a single point. I guess I will need an approach with nodes like this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394942/easiest-way-to-create-simple-connected-graphs/395265?noredirect=1#comment985792_395265

Comment: @skan Moving a tikzmark is like moving a character I think, but there's not really any need to do that. To shorten a line, use `shorten >`/`shorten <`, as you mention. But instead, just use different coordinates for the start and end points of those arrows. e.g. `([yshift=1.2ex]pic cs:a)` for one, and `([yshift=0.8ex]pic cs:a)` for the other. You can of course add an `xshift` in addition to the `yshift`, or use `([shift={(x,y)}]pics cs:a)`.

Comment: what's the parameter to change the angle each arrow departs and arrives?

Comment: @skan See Andrew's answer. I used `bend right`/`bend left`, in my code, and you can specify an angle (e.g. `bend left=70`), but to explicitly set incoming/outgoing angles, use `to[in=0,out=180]` or whatever angles you need.

Comment: My last question, how do yo add the nodes just below the letters, to create vertical lines? https://i.imgur.com/PxTHXki.jpg

Comment: @skan As I said, positioning a `tikzmark` is like positioning a letter. You could do e.g. `\rlap{\hspace{3pt}\raisebox{-2pt}{\tikzmark{ab}}}a` to place the `ab` mark below `a`. Or, with tikzmarks `a` and `b` as in the code above (next to a letter), something like `\draw [->] ([xshift=0.5ex,yshift=-3pt]pic cs:a) coordinate (aa) 
([yshift=2ex]pic cs:b) coordinate (bb)
(aa) -- (aa|-bb);`.

Comment: (In hindsight, this might have been easier by using `\tikz[remember picture] \node (a) {a};` to add the text in the table. Then you could access the anchors of the node directly, and so use e.g. `\draw [->] (a.south) -- (b.north -| a.south);` )

Comment: Could you please add a very simple example of your last idea? For example with the small table?

Comment: @skan See edit.

Comment: Great, now it seems easier to create complex models. I was hesitating about doing it with tikz or externally with Visio or even Powerpoint.

Comment: I have applied your method to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400815/4686...

Comment: How do you add a caption properly to each table?

Comment: @skan (You couldn't have mentioned that four days ago?) Same way you properly caption any other table. See edit.

Comment: How can you easily place a node between two cells, for example bewteen blue and red? Using blue.south east or red.north east sometimes doesn´t look very well placed. I don't need you modify your answer, just a little comment here.

Comment: @skan `\path (a) -- node{foobar} (b);`

Answer (score 8):

Here is a proof of concept using a `matrix of nodes` to produce:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes,
                column sep={6mm,between borders},
                row sep={1.2em,between origins},
                row 1/.style={font=\bfseries, color=blue},
                column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=2em}},
                column 2/.style={nodes={minimum width=5em}},
     ]{ ID & COLOR \\
         1 & blue \\
         1 & red \\
         1 & green \\
         1 & white \\
         2 & red \\
         2 & green \\
     };
     \draw[thick,blue](M-1-1.south west)--(M-1-2.south east);
     \draw[blue](M-1-1.north east)--(M-7-1.south east);
     \draw[thin,blue](M-5-1.south west)--(M-5-2.south east);
     \draw[->,red] (M-2-2.east) to [out=-30, in=30]  (M-5-2.east);
     \draw[->,blue](M-3-2.east) to [out=-30, in=30]  (M-7-2.east);
     \draw[->,blue](M-2-2.west) to [out=210, in=150] (M-6-2.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Details such as having arrows "go over" other arrows are easily addressed as in the examples given in the original question. For the `\matrix` the main point is that the `(M)` after `\matrix` means that the nodes have labels `(M-1-2)`, `(M-1-4)` etc. in the non-empty cells (with the option `nodes in empty cells` you can have nodes in the empty cells too). You can change `(M)` to anything you like. For more details see section 57.1 of the tikz manual.

By playing around with the styling of the rows and columns you can get different effects. For example, if we instead use

```
    \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes,
                column sep={14mm,between origins},
                row sep={1.2em,between origins},
                row 1/.style={font=\bfseries, color=blue},
                column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=2em}},
                column 2/.style={nodes={minimum width=2em}},
```

then the table looks like:

[image]

The only differences in style here that I have used `between origin` for the column separation, changed the amount of separation, and I have changed the minimum width of the nodes in column 2. The net effect, of course, is that the arrows are closer to the text.

Adding extra horizontal and/or vertical rules is straightforward (although, I recommend reading what the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual has to say about vertical rulesO. Changing my choice of colours is also recommended!

**Edit**

If you want to draw arrows between such tables then you need to:

- add `remember picture` to the `tikzpicture` environments
- you need to use different labels in the different `tikzpicture` environments
- you need to add `overlay` to `tikzpicture` environments that use labels from other picture environments.

All of this is explained in section 17.13  of the [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual (version 3.0.1a).

For example, you can draw

[image]

with the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \matrix (M1)[matrix of nodes,
                column sep={14mm,between origins},
                row sep={1.2em,between origins},
                row 1/.style={font=\bfseries, color=blue},
                column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=2em}},
                column 2/.style={nodes={minimum width=2em}},
     ]{ ID & COLOR \\
         1 & blue \\
         1 & red \\
         1 & green \\
         1 & white \\
         2 & red \\
         2 & green \\
     };
     \draw[thick,blue](M1-1-1.south west)--(M1-1-2.south east);
     \draw[blue](M1-1-1.north east)--(M1-7-1.south east);
     \draw[thin,blue](M1-5-1.south west)--(M1-5-2.south east);
     \draw[->,red] (M1-2-2.east) to [out=-30, in=30]  (M1-5-2.east);
     \draw[->,blue](M1-3-2.east) to [out=-30, in=30]  (M1-7-2.east);
     \draw[->,blue](M1-2-2.west) to [out=210, in=150] (M1-6-2.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \hspace*{60mm}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \matrix (M2)[matrix of nodes,
                column sep={14mm,between origins},
                row sep={1.2em,between origins},
                row 1/.style={font=\bfseries, color=blue},
                column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=2em}},
                column 2/.style={nodes={minimum width=2em}},
     ]{ ID & COLOR \\
         1 & blue \\
         1 & red \\
         1 & green \\
         1 & white \\
         2 & red \\
         2 & green \\
     };
     \draw[thick,blue](M2-1-1.south west)--(M2-1-2.south east);
     \draw[blue](M2-1-1.north east)--(M2-7-1.south east);
     \draw[thin,blue](M2-5-1.south west)--(M2-5-2.south east);
     \draw[->,red] (M2-2-2.east) to [out=-30, in=30]  (M2-5-2.east);
     \draw[->,blue](M2-3-2.east) to [out=-30, in=30]  (M2-7-2.east);
     \draw[->,blue](M2-2-2.west) to [out=210, in=150] (M2-6-2.west);
     \draw[ultra thick,orange,->](M1-3-2.east)--node[above,sloped]{transform}(M2-1-1.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've added a complication to break ties.

Comment: This is surely applicable to question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400806/n-base-to-decimal-calculations-in-latex ...

Comment: @jfbu You could certainly draw the "pictures" using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) but I don't see an easy way to use a `tikz` `\matrix`1 since the size will depend on the input. I am tempted to play with it but I spend too much time here already! :)

Comment: I have done it at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400815/4686 but I used the method by @Torbjørn for adding TikZ nodes because I felt more at ease with tabular's.

Comment: How can you easily place a node between two cells, for example bewteen blue and red? Using blue.south east or red.north east sometimes doesn´t look very well placed. I don't need you modify your answer, just a little comment here.

Comment: How do you control the position of the different tables?. (You are using hspace for horizintal positioning, but what about the vertical position?) I need to create a complex example with 6 tables (2x3), and I don't know if it's better to create them independently inside minipages or try to create some as a single table with blank rows or columns inside.

Comment: Another question, one of my tables has a single column, and some of its cells are empty. When I try to reference that cells with  \draw[thin,black, dashed](M2-4-1.south west)--(M2-4-1.south east);  tikz complains saying that node doesn't exist.

Comment: @skan You accepted another answer so not sure why you’d need to know:) 1) add `nodes in empty cells` to the `\matrix` options to reference empty cells 2) load the tiklibrary `calc` package and then you can use `($ (M-1-1)!0.5!(M-2-1) $)` for the point halfway between `(M-1-1-1)` and `(M-2-1)` 3) you can use `\vspace` for vertical space. The best way of arranging many of these tables probably depends on the configuration. It might be easier to put them all in one tikz `\matrix`, or in one `tikzpicture` environment, or in a `tabular` environment or ... It really depends on what you are doing...

Comment: Both answers are great, the other one appeared first, yours at first sight seemed more complex but I'm still hesitating.

Comment: @skan :) Drawings are always a little complicated.  If you are going to use many of these I would define an environment to hide most of the details. This would also simplify things slightly and make the code easier to read and debug. Happy to add details if you want them

Answer (score 4):

Here is a short solution with `pstricks` and `eqmakebox`:

```
   \documentclass[10pt, a4paper, table]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{array, multirow, eqparbox, booktabs}

    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{pst-node, pst-arrow}
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

    \begin{document}

     \begin{pspicture}
     \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12}
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}\fboxsep = 0pt
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{3cm}}c}
    \multirow{7.5}{*}{ \begin{tabular}{c|c}
     \hline
     ID & COLOR \\
     \hline
     1 & \pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{B1}\eqmakebox[L]{~blue~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{B2} \\
     1 & \eqmakebox[L]{~red~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{R} \\
     1 & \eqmakebox[L]{~green~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{G}\pnode[1.5em, 0pt]{LTable} \\
     1 & \pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{W1}\eqmakebox[L]{~white~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{W2} \\
     \hline
     2 & red \\
     2 & green
     \end{tabular}
     % node connections
     \ncarc[arcangle=-40]{B1}{W1}%
     \ncarc[arcangle=50]{R}{W2}
     \ncarc[arcangle=50, border=1pt]{B2}{G}}
     &%
     \begin{tabular}{c!{\color{red}\vrule}c}
    \arrayrulecolor{red}\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{0pt}
     ID & COLOR \\
     \hline
     1 & \pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{C1}\eqmakebox[L]{~blue~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{C2} \\
     1 & \eqmakebox[L]{~red~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{S} \\
    \pnode[-1em, 0pt]{RTable1} 1 & \eqmakebox[L]{~green~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{H} \\
     1 & \pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{X1}\eqmakebox[L]{~white~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{X2} \\
     \end{tabular}
      % node connections
     \psset{linewidth=1pt}
     \ncarc[arcangle=-40]{C1}{X1}%
     \ncarc[arcangle=50]{S}{X2}
     \ncarc[arcangle=50, border=1pt]{C2}{H}
    \bigskip\\
     &
  \begin{tabular}{c!{\color{blue}\vrule}c}
    \arrayrulecolor{blue} \specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{0pt}
     ID & COLOR \\
     \hline
     1 & \pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{C1}\eqmakebox[L]{~blue~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{C2} \\
     \pnode[-1em, 0pt]{RTable2}1 & \eqmakebox[L]{~red~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{T} \\
     1 & \eqmakebox[L]{~green~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{I} \\
     1 & \pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{Y1}\eqmakebox[L]{~white~}\pnode[0pt, 0.6ex]{Y2} \\
     \end{tabular}
     % node connections
     \psset{linewidth=1pt}
     \ncarc[arcangle=-40]{C1}{Y1}%
     \ncarc[arcangle=50]{T}{Y2}
     \ncarc[arcangle=50, border=1pt]{C2}{I}
    \end{tabular}
    \psset{linewidth = 6pt, linecolor=red!80, arrowinset=0, arrowlength=0.8, opacity=0.2}%
    \ncline{LTable}{RTable1}\naput[nrot=:U]{\sffamily\color{red} Transformation 1}
    \ncline[linecolor =blue!80]{LTable}{RTable2}\nbput[nrot=:U]{\sffamily\color{blue} Transformation 2}
     \end{pspicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've added a complication to break ties.

Comment: I see… Where is the downwards arrow supposed to point to? And how are the two tables placed with respect to each other?

Comment: Anywhere you want, is an example

Comment: Is the example I've added like you want?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I can't run your codes. it says  Error: Ghostscript exited with error code 127! C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:708: command failed with exit code 127: perl.exe c:\texlive\2017\texmf-dist\scripts\pdfcrop\pdfcrop.pl "texstudio_BM5676-autopp.pdf" "texstudio_BM5676-pics.pdf".  , I guess it has to do with the postscript, can we do it in a different way?

Comment: You can comment loading `auto-pst-pdf`: it is here to compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape`, so if you do not want to enable -shell-escape, you have to either follow the traditional way: `latex -> dvips -> pstopdf` or compile with `xelatex`.

Comment: I would like to do it with luatex (to keep using the same through a long document).  I've tried replacing postscript with pspicture*  ,  then it compiles but it doesn't show any arrow. Otherwise I'll try to create the picture apart and include it later. I was already using the shell-escape option.

Comment: If I comment out the auto-psd-pdf it casts an error, it doesn't recognize the \ncarc command

Comment: If you remove it, how do you compile?

Comment: I've tried with pdflatex, with luatex (ading \RequirePackage{luatex85} )and also with xetex. In fact I can't run this pstricks example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394942/easiest-way-to-create-simple-connected-graphs  either.

Comment: Actuzlly, the `postscript` environment is known only to `auto-pst-pdf`(hence to `pdflatex`). I've replaced it with `pspicture`, and made some changes for the coloured rules in the right-hand-side columns. Please test my updated code. It works for me.

Comment: I haven't been able to run it, but it isn't yours code's fault but my installation. It's something related with ghostscript or pdfcrop. It's not able to create the "filepics.pdf". 
 I've unsuccessfully tried reinstalling ghostscript, both 64 and 32 bit, and adding it to the path. it's not a problem with permissions because everything else works.

Comment: Under all possible compilation engines?

Comment: latex, pdflatex, luatex not. Under xelatex it generates a pdf with the tables and the word transformation but without arrows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68544/discussion-between-bernard-and-skan).