# Show calculations in base b

Tags: calculations

For showing to my students, I'd like a macro who shows how add, and substract numbers in base b , with b =2 or b=16.

Parameters would be : number1, number2 , et base b in wich number1 and number2 are written.

I 'd like present it like pictures:
[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]
[image: pic4]
[image: pic5]

Has anyone made it?

Xavier.

Comment: a different layout but basically the same calculations as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400806/n-base-to-decimal-calculations-in-latex/400814#400814

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link, but I'don't know how to do . I asked too much: I have changed my question for working with two bases : 2 and 16.

Comment: More closely related (duplicate?) [How to show carries in long addition?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/95812) and also [How to present a vertical multiplication/addition](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/11702)

Comment: Hello, Alan,  Thanks for your comment. I don't want write all calculus, but I want LaTeX to do this( like the package xlop, but with binary and hexadecimal numbers)  .I' don't see it in your links... I'm thinking to a way for doing it.  Thanks you anyway :))).