# n-base fractional to decimal calculations in LaTeX

Tags: mathematics

How can I **visualise** the the conversion of binary floating number or any other base to decimal number in LaTeX?

Example scenario: 11.101 = 2^1 + 2^0 + 2^-1 + 2^-3
However, I would like to visualise this process exactly the same as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400806/n-base-to-decimal-calculations-in-latex/400814#400814). Given link is not suitable for fractional numbers.